# TypeError: ethers.getContractFactory is not a function

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

Im trying to run the partybid contract https://github.com/PartyDAO/partybid from windows powershell but am running into this issue where getContractFactory is not a function

Under helpers.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const ethers = require("ethers");


function loadEnv() {
    dotenv.config();
    const {CHAIN_NAME, RPC_ENDPOINT, DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY} = process.env;
    if (!(CHAIN_NAME && RPC_ENDPOINT && DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY)) {
        throw new Error("Must populate all values in .env - see .env.example for full list");
    }
    return {CHAIN_NAME, RPC_ENDPOINT, DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY};
}

function getDeployer(RPC_ENDPOINT, DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY) {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_ENDPOINT);
    const deployer = new ethers.Wallet(`0x${DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY}`, provider);
    return deployer;
}

async function deploy(wallet, name, args = []) {
    const Implementation = await ethers.getContractFactory(name, wallet);
    const contract = await Implementation.deploy(...args);
    return contract.deployed();
}
```

tried removing the ethers declaration within the file but was thrown a referenceError that ethers not defined instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `ethers` from `hardhat` not from `ethers`.

this

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
```

should be this

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to change require from use hardhat-toolbox to hardhat-walffle

as per may existing you've got these below line in your hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
```

then

Remark it and put a new line with require hardhat-waffle as these below line into the file instead.

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).